# Excel - Distinct Values from a Column on Another Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two sheets in Excel. The first sheet contains a list of samples with some information, where the first row is a header row, and each other row contains information about a sample. The first column contains sample IDs, and some sample IDs are repeated. So, this sheet looks a little like:

```
Sample_ID Var1 Var2 Var3 ...
Sample_A ...
Sample_B ...
Sample_C ...
Sample_A ...
Sample_G ...
Sample_B ...
...
```

For my summary sheet, I would like to get all the distinct sample IDs.

So, I would like something like this:

```
Sample_ID SummaryVar1 ...
Sample_A
Sample_B
Sample_C
Sample_G
...
```

I'm not sure how to program a formula that allows me to return all the distinct values of column A in sheet 1, and put it in column A of sheet 2 (the summary sheet.) The array formulas I've found online don't seem to work properly when referencing another sheet in the formula. Thank you so much.

Comment: You could also create a pivot table on that column. Depending on what you exactly need to do with it, you may opt for selecting the "add this data to the data model" box.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have Excel 365 and the data sheet is Sheet1, try the formula:

```
=UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A8)
```

Replace Sheet1 by your sheet's name.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Excel 365, so I don't have access to UNIQUE().

Comment: @Lyn What version do you have?

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2016